# How to simplify the result of repeated columns after making a COUNT query in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that create an a Count with INNER JOIN's over a Query in MySQL, but I need to SUM the rows repeated after did this query in the TOTAL column. The MySQL query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
    usuarios.nombres_user AS NOMBRE
FROM usuarios
INNER JOIN usuarios_login ON usuarios.id_user = usuarios_login.id_user
INNER JOIN roles ON usuarios_login.id_rol_login = roles.id_rol
INNER JOIN actividades ON actividades.usuario_actividad = usuarios_login.id_login
INNER JOIN prospectos ON prospectos.Id_prospecto = actividades.id_prospecto_actividad
INNER JOIN familias_prospectos ON familias_prospectos.Id_familia_prospecto = prospectos.familia_prospecto_id
INNER JOIN campus ON campus.id_camp = familias_prospectos.id_campus_familias_prospectos
WHERE roles.nombre_rol LIKE '%CRM%'
  AND campus.id_camp = 2
GROUP BY (usuarios_login.id_login), prospectos.Id_prospecto
ORDER BY usuarios.nombres_user ASC
```

This query give me the total count of a user in a column with a GROUP BY and only the TOTAL and NOMBRE values. So, after a did this, I want to simplify the query, like (this is an example that my query did before):

```
My Query give me:
-----------------
TOTAL | NOMBRE
-----------------
   2     John
   1     John
   4     John
   6     Peter
   3     Peter
   1     Peter
   4     Robert
   2     Robert    
And the Goal is try to get:
-----------------
TOTAL | NOMBRE
-----------------
   7     John
   10    Peter
   6     Robert
```

I'm working in PHP and MySQL, there is a way too make it directly with a query in MySQL? I've hope you help me. Thank you.

Comment: SELECT nombre, SUM(total) total FROM (your query) GROUP BY nombre

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use `HAVING`.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)              AS TOTAL,
  usuarios.nombres_user AS NOMBRE
FROM usuarios
  INNER JOIN usuarios_login ON usuarios.id_user = usuarios_login.id_user
  INNER JOIN roles ON usuarios_login.id_rol_login = roles.id_rol
  INNER JOIN actividades ON actividades.usuario_actividad = usuarios_login.id_login
  INNER JOIN prospectos ON prospectos.Id_prospecto = actividades.id_prospecto_actividad
  INNER JOIN familias_prospectos ON familias_prospectos.Id_familia_prospecto = prospectos.familia_prospecto_id
  INNER JOIN campus ON campus.id_camp = familias_prospectos.id_campus_familias_prospectos
GROUP BY (usuarios_login.id_login), prospectos.Id_prospecto
HAVING roles.nombre_rol LIKE '%CRM%' AND campus.id_camp = 2
ORDER BY usuarios.nombres_user ASC
```

Comment: This code gives an error. I'm not using HAVING because i heared that is not the best way to do it. Thank's.

Comment: @Urban Perhaps in your question you should state information like this.

Answer (score 0):

You get duplicates users because you make your `GROUP BY` on 2 values: `id_login` and `Id_prospecto`

You can better understand your result if you add the 2 fields you are grouping on in your `SELECT` statement, like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
    usuarios.nombres_user AS NOMBRE, usuarios_login.id_login, prospectos.Id_prospecto
FROM usuarios
INNER JOIN usuarios_login ON usuarios.id_user = usuarios_login.id_user
INNER JOIN roles ON usuarios_login.id_rol_login = roles.id_rol
INNER JOIN actividades ON actividades.usuario_actividad = usuarios_login.id_login
INNER JOIN prospectos ON prospectos.Id_prospecto = actividades.id_prospecto_actividad
INNER JOIN familias_prospectos ON familias_prospectos.Id_familia_prospecto = prospectos.familia_prospecto_id
INNER JOIN campus ON campus.id_camp = familias_prospectos.id_campus_familias_prospectos
WHERE roles.nombre_rol LIKE '%CRM%'
  AND campus.id_camp = 2
GROUP BY (usuarios_login.id_login), prospectos.Id_prospecto
ORDER BY usuarios.nombres_user ASC
```

Without seeing your data I'll only make a guess: if you want the total per user, just remove `prospectos.Id_prospecto` from the `GROUP BY` so the data will stay grouped at user level :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
    usuarios.nombres_user AS NOMBRE
FROM usuarios
INNER JOIN usuarios_login ON usuarios.id_user = usuarios_login.id_user
INNER JOIN roles ON usuarios_login.id_rol_login = roles.id_rol
INNER JOIN actividades ON actividades.usuario_actividad = usuarios_login.id_login
INNER JOIN prospectos ON prospectos.Id_prospecto = actividades.id_prospecto_actividad
INNER JOIN familias_prospectos ON familias_prospectos.Id_familia_prospecto = prospectos.familia_prospecto_id
INNER JOIN campus ON campus.id_camp = familias_prospectos.id_campus_familias_prospectos
WHERE roles.nombre_rol LIKE '%CRM%'
  AND campus.id_camp = 2
GROUP BY (usuarios_login.id_login)
ORDER BY usuarios.nombres_user ASC
```

If this don't work, you can simply `SUM` the totals with another query  :

```
SELECT SUM(TOTAL), NOMBRE
FROM
(   
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
        usuarios.nombres_user AS NOMBRE
    FROM usuarios
    INNER JOIN usuarios_login ON usuarios.id_user = usuarios_login.id_user
    INNER JOIN roles ON usuarios_login.id_rol_login = roles.id_rol
    INNER JOIN actividades ON actividades.usuario_actividad = usuarios_login.id_login
    INNER JOIN prospectos ON prospectos.Id_prospecto = actividades.id_prospecto_actividad
    INNER JOIN familias_prospectos ON familias_prospectos.Id_familia_prospecto = prospectos.familia_prospecto_id
    INNER JOIN campus ON campus.id_camp = familias_prospectos.id_campus_familias_prospectos
    WHERE roles.nombre_rol LIKE '%CRM%'
      AND campus.id_camp = 2
    GROUP BY (usuarios_login.id_login), prospectos.Id_prospecto
) T
GROUP BY NOMBRE
ORDER BY NOMBRE ASC
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is not working, the error is:  Every derived table must have its own alias in MySQL. The GROUP BY (usuarios_login.id_login), prospectos.Id_prospecto is very important for me for many reasons, and I need to SUM the values repeated. Thanks again.